# Simple SELECT COUNT SQL query error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the **total number of rows** using this SQL query, the result should be = **1**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM offer_process WHERE uid = 103 AND date = '2014-08-20'
```

I don't know exactly how to get the total number of rows from a date (2014-08-20) in this case.

[image]

Comment: Although below answers solves your problem but none of them have provided an optimal solution if you have an index on your date column then below answers will never use an index for your date column because your query is not [**`sargable`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) if you want it to use an index then you have to write a sargable query like `WHERE uid = 103 AND DATE BETWEEN '2014-08-20 00:00:00' AND  '2014-08-20 23:59:59'`

Comment: Thank for your comment, I will think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `datetime` column.
To check only `date` part, use [DATE() MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM offer_process WHERE uid = 103 AND DATE(date) = '2014-08-20'
```

Also, if you have an **index** on your `date` field, you should avoid using `DATE/TIME` MySQL functions. Instead, you can use `WHERE date LIKE '2014-08-20%'` for better performance

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM offer_process WHERE uid = 103 
AND DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m-%d") = '2014-08-20'
```

or you may try using date

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM offer_process
WHERE uid = 103 AND date(`date`) = '2014-08-20'
```

Comment: +1 for `DATE_FORMAT` idea (it's another possibility)

Answer (score 3):

Your date has a time component.  When you use a date constant, it is treated as midnight.  MySQL has the function `date()` to extract just the date component:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM offer_process
WHERE uid = 103 AND date(date) = '2014-08-20'
```

Comment: Shouldn't `date()` be applied to the column, not the constant?

Comment: @MichaelLiu . . . Yes, that would be more consistent with my intention.

Answer (score 2):

To take advantage of the index you might have on the date field I would use:

```
select count(id)
  from offer_process
 where date like '2014-08-20%'
   and uid = 103
```

If you use criteria on a column with a function applied to it, and the index is on the column itself, that index can no longer be used.

Ie. using

```
DATE(date) = '2014-08-20'
```

will result in worse performance. (if the data set is large, and you appropriately have that field indexed).

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e62b/3/0

As you can see from the execution plan, across a larger data set, with the date field indexed, you would have a performance gain as the index can be relied upon. Indexes on the date field cannot be used if you have criteria not on that field but on the result of a function applied against that field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DATE function to compare just the date component:

```
AND DATE(date) = '2014-08-20'
```